# How to list all the tags searched by cscope?

Tags: vim, cscope

I just need a function just like `tags` that will list all the tags match my search. But after i checked the document, i still can't find the correspond util to provide this function. So it's will become very unconvinient after i used `cscope` jumped to one tag and found that this is not the one i needed, and i want to check another one. I have to search again.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the quickfix cscope integration.
Set this in your .vimrc:

```
set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-
```

Then you can do a cscope query and all the hits will be in the quickfix and/or location list.
I prefer to open the location list after a query then I can search the locations. Hit enter to goto that location.

```
:lopen 90
```

Be and sure and read up on vim :help quickfix 
See this doc also:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cscope

Comment: You can also use `:cn` and `:cp` to go forward and backwards between them.  Love cscope/quickfix.